# How to re-use Vuex state fields/actions/mutations between modules?

Tags: vue.js, redux, module, vuex, vuex-modules

So I'm unaware of a Vuex best practice for doing something like this - if there is, please feel free to leave a link so I can do further research.

**What I need is to be able to re-use a set of Vuex `fields/actions/mutations`** between 2 (or possibly more) Vuex modules. I have an application whose Vuex modules' state is closely coupled to their API call schemas.

Perhaps the "best practice" solution is to create a separate Vuex module with the `fields/actions/mutations` I need, but the new module's fields would have to be added to the other modules' state for API calls anyway, which makes the separate module idea seem like more trouble than it's worth.

Here's a basic example:

```
// TodosModule.js

export default {
  state: {
    todos: [],
  },

  actions: {
    async saveTodos({ state }) {
      await this.Api.saveTodos(state.todos);
    },

    setTodos({ commit }, newTodos) {
      commit('SET_TODOS', newTodos);
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_TODOS(state, newTodos) {
      Vue.set(state, 'todos', newTodos);
    },
  },
};
```

```
// HeroesModule.js

export default {
  state: {
    heroes: [],
  },

  actions: {
    async saveHeroes({ state }) {
      await this.Api.saveHeroes(state.heroes);
    },

    setHeroes({ commit }, newHeroes) {
      commit('SET_HEROES', newHeroes);
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    SET_HEROES(state, newHeroes) {
      Vue.set(state, 'heroes', newHeroes);
    },
  },
};
```

I need to be able to add a set of fields to both modules because these fields are needed in their API calls. What that might look like is:

```
// TodosModule.js

export default {
  state: {
    todos: [],
    
    // shared fields are declared somewhere up here
  },

  ...

  actions: {
    async saveTodos({ state }) {
      await this.Api.saveTodos({
        todos: state.todos,
        sharedFieldOne: state.sharedFieldOne,
        sharedFieldTwo: state.sharedFieldTwo,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

What is the best practice, or DRY-est way to do so?

EDIT: I should clarify - I only want the fields placed into the modules - I don't want the fields to share the same value in between modules. Meaning, I don't want the value to change in one module because it changed in another. They should be their own individual references.

There is this part of the Vuex docs:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-reuse

But that seems to be referring to the kind of cross-pollination I don't want. It seems the one value is shared between all of the instances of the field.

Comment: "But that seems to be referring to the kind of cross-pollination I don't want" - can you clarify? Each module will have independent state because of state function, in case that's your concern. You can reuse a store to the point that the resulting store config (state, actions, etc) is exactly what you want. If the whole MyReusableModule from the docs is reusable then that's it. If some actions need to be added then clone the object and add some actions, etc. In your case you can rename "heroes" to "items" in order for names to match between modules

Comment: @EstusFlask so after looking at this further, that turns out to be exactly what I needed. The state fields/actions/mutations need to be declared as functions that return those things so that they don't cross-pollinate.